# Mono.Cecil: How to replace base class

Tags: mono.cecil

I have some classes Like the following:

```
public class MvxEventSourceActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void MethodA()
    {
        DoSomething();
        base.MethodA();
    }
}

public class MvxActivity : MvxEventSourceActivity
{
    ...
}
```

There are a bunch of different subclasses of `Activity` and right now I have to make an `MvxEventSource`/`MvxActivity` pair for each one (Example: `MvxEventSourceListActivity`/`MvxListActivity` that wraps the class `ListActivity` which inherits from `Activity`.  If I was using C++ I could use CRTP to do something like the following:

```
public class MvxEventSourceActivity<TActivity> : TActivity
    where TActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void MethodA()
    {
        DoSomething();
        base.MethodA();
    }
}

public class MvxActivity : MvxEventSourceActivity<Activity>
{
    ...
}
```

But this is C# and I can't do that.  How would I go about using `Fody` to do something like that?